# Unable to Print in FileMaker Pro 18 Advanced under Catalina, message "Change the custom paper size to the correct value, or use Scale to fit"

Tags: catalina, filemaker

As of macOS Catalina upgrade, although I am able to see the Print dialog box, I get this error when I try to click the "Print" button:

[image]

Unable to Print in FileMaker Pro 18 Advanced under Catalina, gets error message "Change the custom paper size to the correct value, or use Scale to fit paper size", ***although "Scale to fit paper size" is already selected***
[image]

Filemaker 18.0.3.317

I am trying to print to a Borther HL-L2300D laser printer and I am running on Mac OS Catalina 10.15.4

2020-05-13
Note; this only happens for me in one file. it happens to be my recipes  (for real!)

recipes.fmp12

Comment: Have you tried printing it to a PDF?   Not export but print.  Then you can open the Pdf and see if there are any problems..

Comment: Are you attempting to use custom paper sizes?  If so, what are they?  Have you tried a standard size like Letter or A4?

Comment: just letter size

Comment: It happens in any paper size

Comment: It happens if I use the "PDF" drop-down in the lower right of the Print dialog, then select "Save as PDF"… same result, the window appears telling me to ON "Scale paper to fit" even though it is already on

Comment: Note; this only happens for me in one file. it happens to be my recipes (for real!) recipes.fmp12

Comment: it appears to only be a problem on my Brother HL-L2300D and it was only a problem in 1 of my (many) FileMaker files. the same file & layout was able to print just fine to a HP LaserJet P1102w